# VBA Invalid type error: CDate doesn't recognize "20xx-mm-dd hh:mm:ss" string variable as date

Tags: vba, ms-access

Really stumped here: My string contains a date and I want to recognise it as such. VBA (Access) doesn't.

From my debugger:

(Q0) `?TypeName(strTMP)`
(A) `String`

(Q1) `?strTMP`
(A)`"2017-03-23 12:35:39"`

(Q2) `?CDate("2017-03-23 12:35:39")`
(A) `23-3-2017 12:35:39`

(Q3) `?IsDate("2017-03-23 12:35:39")`
(A) `True`

(Q4) `?CDate(strTMP)`
(A) `'Error 13 - type mismatch'`

(Q5) `?IsDate(strTMP)`
(A) `False`

In other words:
(0) variable strTMP is a string
(1) proves that the variable strTMP contains a string that is a date
(2) proves that the contents of that string is recognised as a date
(3) proves that the contents of that string is indeed a valid date

If this is all working OK then
in (4) why do I get Error 13 - Type mismatch   and
in (5) why does VBA not recognise strTMP as containing a date ?

Really funny behaviour. How can I get the computer to do what I want ?

Bas

Comment: Seems like your string contains literal quotes. Usually `?strTMP` should return `2017-03-23 12:35:39`, not `"2017-03-23 12:35:39"`. Remove those quotes (not posting this as an answer because I consider this question typo-like if it's the answer)

Comment: I can't replicate this. Can you edit your question to include the failing code instead of the debug output?

Comment: Might be locale specific, because on my computer, (4) works like (2) and (5) give the same answer as (3) (minus the quote as mentioned by @ErikvonAsmuth)

Comment: This works on mine to, try strTemp as "2017-23-03 12:35:39" see what that gives you.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you would edit your question back to such an unreadable format. Please highlight your blocks of code and hit the `{}` button at the top. You can also indent your code with 4 spaces to preserve white space or surround the code with backticks. You can make use of the `<br>` html tag to add a line break without having to punch in two line feeds.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth provided the answer.